# belongsTo relationship empty on save

Tags: ember.js

I have two models that have a relationship, team and teamMember. On a page I'm trying to set it up so that the user can add a new teamMember to a team, but when I'm calling save() it's spitting back that a team must exist, and upon further inspection Ember is not embedding the team in the POST.

team.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  teamMember: DS.hasMany('team-member')
}
```

team-member.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  team: DS.belongsTo('team')
}
```

This is what I have in my route

```
let teamMember = this.get('store').createRecord('teamMember');
let team = this.get('store').findRecord('team', params.teamId).then((results) => {
  teamMember.set('team', results);

  return results;
});
```

I pass the team and the teamMember to a component where I can edit the teamMember, and save it.

```
let teamMember = this.get('teamMember');
// get and set teamMember specific fields
teamMember.save();
```

When I debug from that line I can say teamMember.get('team') and get all of the data, so it seems to be properly set, but all I get from the Rails API is

```
{"team_member"=>{"role_id"=>"0", "phone_number"=>"8888888888"}}
```

And it obviously won't create a team_member without a team to associate it with.

I have a team-member.js serializer:

```
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    team: { embedded: 'always' }
  }
});
```

I do have some stuff in an application serializer, so I'm wondering if it's overwriting the data somehow, but when I debug in that it's still not recognizing the existence of the team.

## Edit/My solution

Knowing that I'm the one with access to the API, I changed everything to JSONAPISerializer. It was serializing the team, but not putting it under "relationships". Then I found the following piece of code.

```
  serialize(snapshot) {
    let serialized = this._super(...arguments);
    let { adapterOptions } = snapshot;
    if (adapterOptions && adapterOptions.updateRelationship === 'tags') {
      return serialized.data.relationships.tags;
    }

    return serialized;
  }
```

I put that in my team-member serializer and it put the team relationship into the proper location.

Comment: What is your applicationSerializer is it a type of DS.RESTSerializer?

Comment: It is a RESTSerializer

Comment: could you post the Json that you are sending in the request to verify that it is making it to the API? If it is it could just be your API not serializing the data properly, If that's case my ASP.Net knowledge will be of no help lol

Comment: If you look in the Ember Inspector (a Chrome addon) can you see if the ids are set properly for the teams? The teams must be persisted before you try to save associated team members. Is the "team must exist" error coming from Rails or Ember? On the outgoing-messages side, it is quite possible your custom serializer is overriding things. Console log all the things.

Comment: @Joe, that's the issue. The Json that it's sending doesn't contain the team details

Comment: @handlebears, Ember Inspector has the correct team set. I'm really starting to wonder if it's the custom serializer messing with it.

Comment: When you look at the team itself though, does it definitely have an ID field named modelname_id (or maybe just I'd, I forget)? Initial serialization of the id, after fetch/post not just the other attributes from the model, is one of the main causes of the error. If it does, then I agree with your suspicion.

Comment: @handlebears, I got it figured out. See my edit. I'm not sure if there's something else that should really be happening, but this is an acceptable workaround for me.

Comment: @ELepolt eh, looks good to me! The kind of thing custom serializers are for